# Looking for a way to extract email addresses from a distribution list with active directory

Tags: perl, vbscript, active-directory

I am looking for a way to connect to Active Directory and extract email addresses for a distribution list. I dont mind if it is a solution using a tool such as dsquery or dsget or if it is scripting via vbscript or perl. I have been able to extract email addresses at the ou level but not for distribution lists. My knowledge of how active directory works is limited (still reading up on it).

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the lightweight active directory protocol? This is where I would start: http://snipplr.com/view/4646/get-members-of-an-active-directory-distribution-group/